# Phonegap Plugin

Tags: apache-cordova, plugin

Olá, sou iniciante com phonegap/cordova, e venho tendo dificuldades para entender algumas coisas, como por exemplo, instalar plugins, não importa da maneira que eu faça, quando eu buildo do projeto no próprio site do phonegap https://build.phonegap.com, ele não detecta os plugins que foram inseridos.

Por exemplo, esse simples plugin de email:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/tree/cab303d

Eu instalo via console: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git`

E insiro no meu xml a referencia: `<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2" />`

E depois buildo ele no site, e em plugins não aparece esse plugin inserido.

Se alguém que tiver experiencia com app híbrido puder me esclarecer, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Se você vai usar o `PhoneGap Build` não precisa instalar o plugin via console, apenas no `config.xml`
Pra você instalar um plugin via `git` é só fazer assim:

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" source="git" />
```

depois zipar seus arquivos e mandar para o `PhoneGap Build`.
E não se esqueça de adicionar o `.js` do seu plugin la no seu `index.html` pra ele poder funcionar ;)